# Python Selenium will stall if window is left in background

Tags: python, selenium

I have a setup where I create a `Remote` driver (with Chromedriver), go to a website, perform actions on it. I'm running the driver with `headless=False`, so Selenium creates a Chrome window.

When I have the Chrome window open and in foreground, everything works just fine.
When I have it reduced to icon, or even open but in background - so using other apps when Selenium is working -, then the driver **can** stall - but it will, like 80% of the times.

When this happens, I have to reopen the Chrome window and, if this fails to resume the execution, I have to go to the running script's terminal and press Enter - so send an event to the script -; usually this solves the stall, and the execution will continue.

I know that, when running with `headless=True`, this problem doesn't show up; however I cannot use it, since the website in question will change the page according to this setting, so my currently situation is running this script with this Chrome window in front of me.

The script execution will last from 5 to 10 minutes everytime it's runned, if this can may be related to the problem.

Is there anything I can do to mitigate, or even remove this problem at all?

Comment: just don't use the headless argument at all or use `driver.minimize_window()` if you want to minimize it

Comment: @CatChMeIfUCan I don't want to minimize the window, I want the execution to continue as if the window were in foreground.

Comment: can you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: It's very long and not useful for this problem; the intended answer I expect is something like a change in the Chromedriver binary, or even in the Selenium library, because this behaviour it's not code-dependant

Comment: in that case, it may be a flaw in chromedriver have you tried firefox geckodriver?